# Wildfly disable log to server.log

Tags: logging, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 15 and I would like to disable stack trace log to server.log and stderr.

I added the file *./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and I configured the *logback.xml* file.

Unfortunately the stack trace is not logged in the application log file defined in logback.xml configuration but it's logged in server.log file and in stderr:

```
    2020-03-18 11:32:33,768 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /app/sample/: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sample error !!!
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:247)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
```

My application log file contains all logs and just the error message for the exception above.

How can I avoid this behaviour and have the complete stack trace in the application log file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently nothing that can be done about that. Because Undertow is part of the server the stack trace will be logged to the default log context which is defined in the logging subsystem.